# Selenium with Python, trying to click a "pseudo element"

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do web scraping of a page, everything went normal until I figured out, there is a "pseudo element"  (::before), let me show you

[image]

*btw, the inspector is above the "Magnifier Glass"*

So the problem comes with detalle_causa = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'i.fa.fa-search.fa-lg').click()

```
if t_rol == rol_yr:
        rol_c0.append(t_rol)
        materias_e_c0.append(t_tiporecurso)
        carat_c0.append(t_caratulado)
        fecha_c0.append(t_fecha)
        estado_c0.append(t_estado)
        data = {"ROL": rol_c0,"TIPO RECURSO":materias_e_c0, "CARATULADO":carat_c0, "FECHA":fecha_c0, "ESTADO":estado_c0}
        sleep(3)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df)
        sleep(3)
        detalle_causa = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'i.fa.fa-search.fa-lg').click()
        print(detalle_causa)
        df.to_csv('2022_cs_p2.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
        sleep(2)

 else:
     print("No era")
```

EDIT: I need to get access to this.

[image]

So if you guys could give me a hand here, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: some pointers here https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/handling-pseudo-elements-in-css-with-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

```
detalle_causa = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'i.fa.fa-search.fa-lg')
detalle_causa.click()
print(detalle_causa)
```

You are trying to store a click.

Comment: Your print statement is going to print nothing human readable... it's going to print the guid for the webelement, etc. I'm not sure what you are intending to print here given that it's an icon so even `detalle_causa.text` is not going to print anything either.

Comment: The problem is with detalle_causa, since I already copy/paste the selector, created the variable and added the click at the end. From that I'm not getting access to the 3rd image website, which is the goal

Comment: Was unsure of what he was trying to print to so I just printed the guid.